# Validating a single radio button is not working in available javascript validation script

Tags: javascript, validation, radio-button

I have randomly generated radio button series like

```
<input type="radio" name="creatorusers" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="creatorusers" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="creatorusers" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="creatorusers" value="1">
.....so on
```

But I get only ONE radio button and execute the javascript validation given for it to chk whether the radio button is selected or not, then it doesnt work
Ples help me out in resolving this.

```
mycreator = -1;

  for (i=frm.creatorusers.length-1; i > -1; i--) {
  if (frm.creatorusers[i].checked) {
  mycreator = i; i = -1;
  }
  }
  if (mycreator == -1) {
  alert("You must select a Creator User!");
  return false;
  }
```

Comment: when i alert the "frm.creatorusers.length" i get alert as "undefined" but at other side when there more than on radio button then this validation works fine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Always (!) use the var keyword. Otherwise your variables will be in the global scope (yes, even those in function bodies), which can make for some bugs that are hard to track down.

As [@Felix pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4574049/validating-a-single-radio-button-is-not-working-in-available-javascript-validatio/4574075#4574075), `creatorusers` will only be an array if there is more than one element with that name in the form. You can create a single-element array when necessary to work around that.

Here is an abstracted function that can validate an arbitrary checkbox list.

```
function ensureChecked(checkboxes, error) {
  if (checkboxes) {
    var cbx = (checkboxes.length > 0) ? checkboxes : [checkboxes]; 
    for (var i=0; i<cbx.length; i++) {
      if (cbx[i].checked) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    alert(error);
  }
  return false;
}
```

call as

```
ensureChecked(frm.creatorusers, "You must select a Creator User!");
```

Comment: I get this error: frm.creatorusers is undefined
[Break On This Error] var rdo = (frm.creatorusers.length >...rm.creatorusers : frm.creatorusers;  in firebug

Comment: @OMThe: This means that `frm.creatorusers` is undefined (duh). Obviously there is not aleways a form field with this name. Just check if it exists beforehand. *(It also means that you are not really using my code, but something else. I don't understand why you accepted my answer then, and why you un-accepted it as your code stopped working.)*

Comment: Make sure to pass the form!!!  `onsubmit="return validate(this)"` - this will also make naming the form unnecessary. If you however use document.getElementById("ID_OF_FORM") make sure the form HAS an ID and not just a name. IE will allow getElementById("NAME_OF_FORM") but other browsers will not

Answer (score 3):

Ah now I got. If you only have one radio button, then `frm.creatorusers` is not an array. Just skip it:

```
var mycreator = -1;
var checked = false;

if(typeof frm.creatorusers.length === 'number') {
    for (var i=frm.creatorusers.length; i--; ) {
      if (frm.creatorusers[i].checked) {
          mycreator = i;
          checked = true;
          break;
      }
    }
}
else if(frm.creatorusers.checked){
    mycreator = //? what here?
    checked = true;
}

if(!checked) {
     alert("You must select a Creator User!");
     return false;
}
```

If `mycreator` was just for checking whether a button was selected or not, you can completely remove it from the code above.

Some further notes to your code:

- Always declare variables with `var`, otherwise they will be global.
- Use `break` to end a loop.
- Maybe it is just because of copy and paste, but having a lot of radio buttons with the same value does not make much sense.

Comment: kling answer for ur last point, its just sample hence its just a copy paste, Secondly ur code is not is not working, It always give the msg "You must select a Creator User!"

Comment: @OMThe Eternity: The code works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/TbNux/ There is probably something else wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
function validate(frm){
    var isChecked = false;

    for (var i=0; i<frm.elements.length; i++)
    {
       if (frm.elements[i].type === 'radio'){
         if (frm.elements[i].checked === true){
           isChecked = true;
           break;
         }
       }
    }

    if (isChecked === true){
       return true;
    }
    else{
       alert('You should select an option first !');
    }
}
```

Now you should call above function on `onsubmit` event of the form:

```
<form onsubmit="return validate(this);">
```

Now the `validate` function will make sure that at least one radio button is checked otherwise it won't submit.

Comment: Identity comparison is nice and all, but could it be that you are overdoing it? :) E.g. `isChecked` can never be anything but boolean in your code, so `return isChecked` is a safe bet. Also, what is `j`?

Comment: Whee doies the "j" come from?

Comment: I edited your answer to pass the form in the function and not use getElementById in case there IS no ID on the form. See other comment of mine on this page

Answer (score 1):

this should do it

```
function isRadioSelected(btn) {

    if(typeof btn.length === 'number') {
        for(var i=0;i<btn.length;i++)
            if(btn[i].checked) return true

    }else{
        if(btn.checked) return true
    }

    return false

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this instead:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">     
function confirmsubmit() {
       var btn = document.formname.buttonname

       if (btn.checked == false) 
       {
        window.alert("You did not click the button.");
        btn.focus();
        return false;
        }

        return true;
}
</script>
</head>

<body>

<form method="post" action="mailto:youremail@yourdomain.com" 
name="formname" onsubmit="return confirmsubmit();">
click here: <input type="radio" name="buttonname"><br />

    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"></p>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```