# Validating a single radio button is not working in available javascript validation script Part-2

Tags: javascript, validation, radio-button

I am available with the solution given by @Tomalak for [MY QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4574049/validating-a-single-radio-button-is-not-working-in-available-javascript-validatio) could you pls help me out with it as its giving me an error in firebug as : **frm.creatorusers is undefined
[Break On This Error] var rdo = (frm.creatorusers.length >...rm.creatorusers : frm.creatorusers;**
 I used the code for validating radio button as:

```
function valDistribution(frm) {
var mycreator = -1;
        var rdo = (frm.creatorusers.length > 0) ? frm.creatorusers : frm.creatorusers; 
         for (var i=0; i<rdo.length; i++) {
         if (rdo[i].checked) {
         mycreator = 1;
            //return true;
          }
          }
          if(mycreator == -1){
          alert("You must select a Creator User!");
  return false;

          }

}
```

Comment: WHoever is downvoter give me the reason for ur vote

Comment: I did not vote you down however: 1) you are NOT using the correct code given to you 2) you do not show where you are calling valDistribution and 3) why not FINISH one question before asking the same again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to use the code you were given by @Tomalak but did not copy correctly

```
function valDistribution(frm) { // frm needs to be passed here
  var myCreator=false;
// create an array if not already an array
  var rdo = (frm.creatorusers.length > 0) ? frm.creatorusers : [frm.creatorusers];  
  for (var i=0; i<rdo.length; i++) {
    if (rdo[i].checked) {
      myCreator=true;
      break; // no need to stay here
    }
    if (!myCreator){
      alert("You must select a Creator User!");
      return false;
    }
    return true; // allow submission
  }
```

assuming the onsubmit looking EXACTLY like this:
`<form onsubmit="return valDistribution(this)">`

and the radio NAMED like this:
`<input type="radio" name="creatorusers" ...>`

Answer (score 2):

You can try this script:

```
<html>
  <script language="javascript">
   function valbutton(thisform) {
   myOption = -1;
   alert(thisform.creatorusers.length); 
   if(thisform.creatorusers.length ==undefined) {
     alert("not an array");
     //thisform.creatorusers.checked = true;
     if(thisform.creatorusers.checked) {
       alert("now checked");
       myOption=1;              
       alert("You selected button number " + myOption
         + " which has a value of "
         + thisform.creatorusers.value);    
     }
   }
   else {
     for (i=thisform.creatorusers.length-1; i > -1; i--) {
       if (thisform.creatorusers[i].checked) {
         myOption = i; i = -1;
       }
     }
     if (myOption == -1) {
       alert("You must select a radio button");
       return false;
     }
     alert("You selected button number " + myOption
       + " which has a value of "
       + thisform.creatorusers[myOption].value);
   }
}
</script>
    <body>
    <form name="myform">
<input type="radio" value="1st value" name="creatorusers" />1st<br />
<!--<input type="radio" value="2nd value" name="creatorusers" />2nd<br />-->
<input type="button" name="submitit" onclick="valbutton(myform);return false;" value="Validate" />
<input type="reset" name="reset" value="Clear" />
</form> 
</body>    
</html>
```

Comment: MAnn its displaying Error thats y i have reposted the question with same link, else why would I have reposted it?

Comment: As available in the previous{linked} question it can have mulitple radio buttons and also it ca have a single radio button, Its dynamic

Comment: I have modified the code to accept single and multiple radio buttons

Comment: The forum may not be able to give you the exact working code, but can point out work around.

Comment: @UNNI Its still gives me same error "frm.creatorusers is undefined"

Comment: This code works fine in ff and IE.It still run in my system.Clear the cache and run this code.The code handles for single and multiple radio buttons

Comment: @mplungjan can you please confirm this above code snippet works.OM The Entity has some other issues, I think

Comment: It may work, however the array ternary from Tomalak is more elegant